# Match nilable string ignoring case in elixir

Tags: elixir

Is it possible to pattern matching of nilable string regardless of case?

I want something like this :

```
def matcher(str) do
    case String.downcase(str) do
        "correct" -> true
        _ -> false
    end 
end
```

Expected results:

```
matcher("") # false 
matcher("correct") # true 
matcher("CorrecT") # true 
matcher(nil) # false.
```

The problem with the above code is that `matcher(nil)` causes `FunctionClauseError`. Of cause, I can use a helper method that checks for nil case, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is to restrict the function arguments to binary only before doing `String.downcase(str)` on the argument. Everything else should be explicitly matched fo `false`:

```
def matcher(str) when is_binary(str) do
  String.downcase(str) == "correct"
end 
def matcher(_), do: false
```

`nil` which is in turn *an atom* will be matched and processed by second clause, returning `false`. Note, that this approach is safer than an explicit check for `is_nil(str)` because it returns `false` for anything unexpected.